# WaitAll blocks UI

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a site scraper that scrapes a site with paging results.

For every page I try to run a Task to make it faster, but the freezes.

```
var pageCount = getPageCount(txtSearchQuery.Text);
var tasks = new Task[pageCount];

var link = txtSearchQuery.Text;
for (var i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
{

    tasks[i-1] = new Task(new Action(() => { Scrape(link, i); }));
    tasks[i-1].Start();
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
MessageBox.Show("Complete");
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `WaitAll` is a blocking operation.  The tasks may run in parallel but `WaitAll` will block for as long as it takes the longest running task to finish.

Comment: *What I am doing wrong?* You are *waiting* for all the tasks to finish. That blocks the current (UI) thread.

Comment: you've got a wpf app, why aren't you using `async`/`await`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*I am assuming you are using the latest version of .net that supports async/await*

Change your method signature to make it async and await the result of your tasks using Task.WhenAll. This will free up the UI thread ie. won't hang the UI.

```
// normally you do not return void but a Task BUT with WPF events 
// (like on button click) void is required instead
protected async void MyMethod() {

    // Task.WaitAll(tasks); // replace this with
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // this will not hang your UI

   // rest of your code that you want to execute
}
```

Comment: A question: Where should we put the code we wish to execute after all tasks completed? I think the OP will want to know where to use this code :)

Comment: @J3soon - Immediately after the await. The code will continue to process the Tasks but on a different thread. The UI thread is returned to the window so there is no freeze. Its all inline.

Comment: No offense, I'm just saying that you can put something like `// Do continuation work.` after the `await` line, since `async / await` can be confusing.

Comment: @J3soon - none taken, I was literally typing it out as you posted this last comment :)

Comment: @J3soon async/await is fairly well documented...not sure the comment was necessary but I suppose it can't hurt either :).

Comment: @Igor Is there a way to set a callback to fire when a Task from the array completes?

Comment: @giannisf - sure. When any task completes or when a specific task completes? You can also change it to await each task in your loop and provide code immediately following. It just depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Igor any task. I want to let the user know that a page completed. (update a Label)

Comment: @giannisf - if the page completed then you want all the tasks in which case what I have above works fine. Any task will call back when the first one completes but others might still be processing. If that is still your intent you can replace `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` with `await Task.WhenAny(tasks);` and code will resume execution as soon as any one of your tasks completed.

Answer (score 3):

WaitAll is going to block the Main thread. Instead use ContinueWhenAll and do your work in there after all the tasks are completed.

```
var link = txtSearchQuery.Text;
for (var i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
{

    tasks[i-1] = new Task(new Action(() => { Scrape(link, i); }));
    tasks[i-1].Start();
}

Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, completedTasks =>
{
// Do continuation work.
});
```

Comment: Basically set a `callback` like in `js`?

Comment: ContinueWhenAll also starts a task with the Action given in second argument after all the tasks in first argument are completed. you can consider it as a callback.